# xlsx to csv: unwantedly asks for confirmation, cannot select range

Tags: csv, vbscript, automation, export-to-csv, xlsx

When I want to convert a xlsx file into a csv with the following code:

```
WorkingDir = "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\example.xlsx"

Dim fso, FileName, SaveName, myFile
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
Set myFile = fso.GetFile(WorkingDir)

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = True

FileName = Left(myFile, InStrRev(myFile, "."))
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(myFile)
objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:C2").Select
SaveName = FileName & "csv"
objWorkbook.SaveAs SaveName, 23
objWorkbook.Close

Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
```

It works but asks me if i want to save my changes in the example.csv file. The saving should work without confirming and also should overwrite an eventually existing .csv file.
The second problem is that the range command where i select a specific part (rows and coumns) of the example.xlsx file which will be converted into a .csv file doesnt work. But there is no error. It seems that the vbscript jumps over this command. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try telling Excel that the file is already saved

```
objWorkbook.Saved = true
objWorkbook.Close
```

In terms of saving your select range, you could try

```
objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:C2").Copy
dim sheet: set sheet =  objWorkbook.Sheets.Add()
' Add()ing should actually activate the sheet
' sheet.Activate
sheet.Paste
' SaveAs will save the active sheet
objWorkbook.SaveAs FileName, 23
```

In otherwords, you need to duplicate the data in a second worksheet then save that worksheet as your csv. Closing the workbook (xlsx) without saving it will discard that new sheet.

Comment: @nolags great! i surprise myself sometimes